# need to keep items inline but must use display:block with div tags

Tags: inline, block, html

this is pretty frustrating...

basically i'm creating a menubar on a site, and have used css sprite to have a hover effect where the image changes as you hover over it. this is working fine, but i can't display multiple images inline because i have to use display:block in the css for the sprite/hover class for it to work.

here is some of the css code i have:

```
.x a {display:block; width:100px; height:100px; overflow:hidden;}
.x a:hover img {margin-left:-100px;}
/* ie6 needs this fix*/
.x a:hover {zoom:1;}
```

and then here is the code in the php file (it's part of a wordpress theme, this bit going in the header.php file):

```
<div class='x'><a href='#' alt='#'><img src='#' /></a></div>
```

note: the image used is a horizontal sprite, so two images merged into one (100x100 turned into 200x100).

this alone works fine, but then when i add something to it like:

```
<div class='x'><a href='#' alt='#'><img src='#' /></a></div> &nbsp; 
<div class='x'><a href='#2' alt='#2'><img src='#2' /></a></div>
```

it makes it go to a new line. i thought it may be a padding issue where it's overflowing on the line, but i've tried doing just two images (total area taken up maybe 210px) and it's in a 911px container area and still goes to a new line.

i've tried using < span> tags, tables, inline-block, and several other things but still no success. at one point i got it to stay inline but then the image was placed beneath all the others, in the correct horizontal position but wrong vertical position.

the goal is to have about 8 100x100 images all in a row in the menu bar, with one spacing in between each one, in a container with width 911px. they all will be in the 'x' class so that the image changes when hovered over.

sorry for writing so much but wanted to get it clear. please help!

Comment: i should also note that my css skills are quite bad so i apologise!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `div`s are rendering as blocks, which is why the images aren't sitting beside eachother.

If I understand what you're trying to achieve correctly, adding a rule

.x { display: inline-block }

will do what you want.

I made a JSFiddle to try it out: http://jsfiddle.net/XZWzW/

Comment: yes! thank you so much, works perfectly. can't thank you enough.